# Explanation request of a paragraph in a VFD manual about a diode, should I add it or not?

Tags: diodes, relay, vfd

I didn't fully understand this paragraph in a [VFD manual](https://download.sew-eurodrive.com/download/pdf/11697415.pdf):

My question is: is the free-weeling diode exist inside the drive, or should I put an external one? [image]
[image]

Comment: If using a relay then a diode across the relay coil needs to be added.

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title.

Comment: And please refer to the manual. And I think you could remove all pictures and add a new picture only containing section 9.11.2. Or easier, use the ```> Blockquote``` option to post only the relevant text

Comment: @Huisman, I don't know how to do this things, I'm a new user. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: By cropping the images. Or safe the PDF to a hard drive and print it again to new PDF file. That removes the copy/paste protection. I've added the link to the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @Andyaka comments is correct.

> If using a relay then a diode across the relay coil needs to be added

The datasheet says the same. The sentence is:

> The binary output DOØ2 '/Brake' is configured as an output for operating **a relay with free-wheeling diode**...".

The relay and free-wheeling diode are mentioned as a whole.

BTW, the DOØ2 is likely a typo, this should be DBØØ.

Since the brake is likely far away, you want a free-wheeling diode as close as possible to the brake instead of in the driver. You want to minimize the current loop area.